# Is importing a character from Mass Effect 1 to Mass effect 2 worthwhile?

Tags: mass-effect-series

I have ME 1 for Xbox 360 and ME 2 on PC. I've played neither. I've heard there is an import character feature in ME 2. Am I missing out on anything if I don't play the games on the same platform?

Comment: A couple of decisions will be made for you if you don't import. From ME1 to ME2 it doesn't matter much, since ME2 is pretty linear. And then there's ME3 whose best ending can only be achieved if you import a game from ME1 + ME2.

Comment: ME2 is "pretty linear"? Did we play the same game?

Answer (score 2):

If continuing **your** story is important to you, then yes.

You can use a save editor to set all of the choices from 1, not just the few major ones that the game lets you do. Through that you could set the exact choices for your ME2 playthrough, at which point you'll miss nothing at all.

---

The actual gameplay is extremely different from 1 to the rest of the series, just so you are aware. So skip to 2 if 1 is not fun to play.

Comment: Yeah, a save editor will go a long way if you want to keep things yours and not lose out with the premade choices (e.g. there are some characters that are a lot more fun if you *didn't* make the same choices as the default (e.g. a salesman on the Citadel won't be as nice if you let the Council die)).

Comment: There's also a chance to lock in DLC choices too without you having to buy them. You can also set your relationships to an exact value, which is helpful if you wanted to full on romance someone but didn't know exactly how.